# Output a list of lists from 2 separate lists in a specific format

Tags: python-3.x, list

Let's say you have an initial list, 
    `list_1 = [a, b, c]`.

You run a function which returns a new list, 
    `list_2 = [x, y]`

How can I combine the two lists into the form 
   `list_3 = [[a, b, c, x], [a, b, c, y]]`

Comment: Hi and Welcome on SO. Please provide your attemps and your results so someone can help you. Please read [ask] adn [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [list_1 + [x] for x in list_2]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by creating a copy of list_1 and working on that. See the code below:

**Code**

```py
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['x', 'y']
ml=[]     # master list which will be the final output
ls=[]     # copy of list_1 which we will use
for i in list_2:
    ls=list_1.copy()
    ls.append(i)
    ml.append(ls)
    ls=[]
```

**Output**

ml:

```py
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**map** will use **modify_list** function to append each element of *list_2* with *list_1*.

```
import functools

list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_2 = ['x', 'y']

def modify_list(given_list, element):
    temp_list = given_list.copy()
    temp_list.append(element)
    return temp_list

list_3 = list(map(functools.partial(modify_list, list_1), list_2))
```

**Output**:

```
[['a','b','c','x'],['a','b','c','y']]   # print(list_3)
```

Comment: Generally, an answer should have a bit more explanation to it beyond just code - it needs to be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Improved version of above code is:
`list_3 = list(map(lambda elem: list_1 + [elem], list_2))`
it will achieve the same result by append each element of list_2 with list_1